# c++ Get chars individually including spaces

Tags: c++, char, spaces

Say we have this code:

```
char nextChar;
std::string nextTerm;
bool inProgram = true;
while (inProgram)
{   
    std::cin.get(nextChar);              
    while (nextChar != ' ')
    {             
        nextTerm.push_back(nextChar);             
        std::cin.get(nextChar); 
    }
    //Parse each term until program ends
}
```

Basically my goal here is to get each char individually and add to to a string (nextTerm), until it comes across a space, then stop to parse the term. This seems to just skip over spaces and directly get characters from the following word when two words are inputted. This seems like it would be simple yet I can't figure it out. Help is appreciated.

EDIT:
It ends up that get does not skip spaces, and that it was a problem later in my program that was causing them to merge. Thanks for all the comments and help.

Comment: @Matthew Excactly so

Comment: Maybe you need to tell the input stream to [not skip spaces](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/noskipws).

Comment: Is your problem that you want spaces added to `nextChar` instead of being skipped over?

Comment: Oh, so you want the outer while loop (the inProgram one) to end after it detects a space?

Comment: I had to make minor changes to run in a demo environment, but I believe I've proven that your "space-detecting" code works just fine: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/eeb3c05e639813e0 So can you present a [verifiable testcase](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) please? Thanks.

Comment: @Matthew no, I want the inner while loop to end after it detects a space, so that the program can then act based on what nextTerm is.

Comment: Why don't you just do repeated formatted extraction into a `std::string`? That'll already pull out one whitespace-separated token (i.e. a word) at a time. No need for all these loops and `push_back`s, surely...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think of the following ways to resolve the problem.

1. Clear `nextTerm` before the inner `while` loop.

   ```
   char nextChar;
   std::string nextTerm;
   bool inProgram = true;
   while (inProgram)
   {
      // Clear the term before adding new characters to it.
      nextTerm.clear();

      std::cin.get(nextChar);              
      while (nextChar != ' ')
      {             
         nextTerm.push_back(nextChar);             
         std::cin.get(nextChar); 
      }
      //Parse each term until program ends
   }
   ```
2. Move the definition of `nextTerm` inside the outer `while` loop.

   ```
   char nextChar;
   bool inProgram = true;
   while (inProgram)
   {   
      // A new variable in every iteration of the loop.
      std::string nextTerm;

      std::cin.get(nextChar);              
      while (nextChar != ' ')
      {             
         nextTerm.push_back(nextChar);             
         std::cin.get(nextChar); 
      }
      //Parse each term until program ends
   }
   ```